# no MySQL application after installation

Tags: mysql, windows-10

only "MySQL for Visual Studio" item when running mysql-installer-community-8.0.26.0.msi. Only "MySQL Shell" and a "MySQL Workbench", but not "MySQL" application after installation

Comment: `MySQL Workbench` is an application and `MySQL Shell` let's you manage through a command prompt. What specifically are you looking for? Have you used MySQL before?

Comment: I plan to use MySQL + Golang to study. A few years ago, I installed MySQL on my computer to study website creation.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My problem is that MySQL installer provided me with a list of only one application and did not install an application that I can call from a program.